# Cannot add directory to the view

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I've tried to add directory c:\mscache which is read only and hidden, to my view, but I'm getting following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::filesystem3::filesystem_error'
  what():  boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::construct: Access is denied: "C:/MSOCache"
```

I don't want to do anything in this directory just read its contents. How shall I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a directory that the OS doesn't normally want programs to *access* (write or read). Since BFS has no provisions for directories that require OS-specific permissions, you're going to have to use OS-specific API calls to talk to it.